# Java SWT unwanted system beeps

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, system

Is there a way to disable unwanted system beeps in swt, like on error events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anything that calls `Display.beep()` directly, the answer is no.

I have been looking through the code that calls `beep()` and it does not look like there are anything conditional there either.

So, you're only chance is if your operating system have a some way to disable beeps from a specific application...